# highlighting duplicates between multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a 3 non consecutive column ranges: D25:D31, G25:G31, J25:J31.

I want to highlight duplicate values. The value is considered duplicate if it occures more than once in 
the whole range, meaning even between different columns.

Example:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Note that the columns with time are not to be highlighted, only the 3 smaller columns are considered for duplicates.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIF({$D$25:$D$31;$G$5:$G$31;$J$25:$J$31},D25)>1
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is just to enter a custom formula which adds the counts for the three columns and tests to see if the total is greater than one (but only if the value is text not number):

```
=and(istext(D25),countif($D$25:$D$31,D25)+countif($G$5:$G$31,D25)+countif($J$25:$J$31,D25)>1)
```

[image]